# Continuous functional such that $f(x_0)\ne 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I read that in any locally convex topological space $X$, not necessarily a Hausdorff space but with linear operations continuous, for any $x_0\ne 0$ we can define a continuous linear functional $f:X\to K$ such that $f(x_0)\ne 0$.

I cannot find a proof of that anywhere and cannot prove it myself. Please correct me if I am wrong, but I think that if $A$ is closed in $X$ and $x_0\in A$ there exist a continuous linear functional rigorously separating $x_0$ and $A$, but I am not sure whether we can use that...
Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In locally convex spaces, you can use the Hahn–Banach theorem. Take a functional on the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $x_0$ and extend to the whole space.

More generally, in a topological vector space $V$ you will find such a functional if and only if $V$ contains a convex, open proper subset which contains $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I have a doubt: in a normed space we can chose $p:V\to K,x\mapsto\|x\|$ as a seminorm majorating the linear functional $f_0:\text{Span}(x_0)\to K,x=\alpha x_0\mapsto \alpha$, but if $V$ isn't normed what can we use as $p$?

Comment: Use the Minkowski functional of some convex, balanced, open and proper neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Comment: I know that $0$ always has a convex and balanced neighbourhood in such a space, though I don't understand how to be sure there is a proper one and how to build one for $x_0$... I even supposed a trivial space is locally convex... :-( Once chosen such a neighbourhood, say $C$, how can I see that $|f(\alpha x_0)|\leq p_C(\alpha x_0),\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$? $\infty$ thanks!!!

Comment: The map $x\mapsto x+x_0$ is a homeomorphism. Just take a suitable neighbourhood of the origin and translate it by $x_0$.

Comment: So, I see that for an open neighbourhood $C\in\mathcal{N}(0)$ of 0 the topological and algebraic interiors coincide with $C$ and the Minkowski functional $p_C$ is such that $C=\{x\in X:p_C(x)<1\}$. It's then possible to write any element of the convex open $C-x_0\in\mathcal{N}(x_0)$ as $y+x_0,y\in C$ and see, thanks to the convexity and positive homogeneity of $p_C$, that $p_C(y+x_0)<1+p_C(x_0)$. I interestingly notice that, because of absorbance and balancedness, for any direction $v\in X$ the affine line $x_0+\text{Span}(v)$ contains a segment in $C+x_0$...

Comment: Though, I'm not able to build a functional such that $f_0(x)\leq p_C(x)$ in a 1-dimensional subspace... $\infty$ thanks!!!

Comment: Why? How about $\alpha x \mapsto \alpha p_C(x)$. The right hand side depends on $\alpha$ only.

Comment: I know that for a convex set $C$ containing 0 in its algebraic interior the Minkowski functional has the homogeneity property $\lambda\geq 0\Rightarrow p_C(\lambda x)=\lambda p_C(x)$. If $C$ is balanced and I'm understanding, that implies (I write the complex case only, immediately extensible to $\mathbb{R}$) that $\forall\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\quad p_C(\lambda x)=|\lambda|p_C(x)$. Correct?

Comment: If that's correct, and we chose $f_0(\alpha x'):=\alpha p_C(x')$, for any $x=\alpha x'\in\text{Span}(x')$ we can majorate $|f(x)|=|p_C(\alpha x')|=|\alpha| p_C(x')\leq p_C(\alpha x')$. As $x'$, should I chose $x_0$? I'm not sure how to see that, for such a choice, $f_0(x_0):=p_C(x_0)>0$... $\aleph_1$ thanks!!!